# R: Why is `pcr` in `qualityTools` rejecting vectors?

Tags: r, vector, types

I'm trying to use the `pcr` function within the `qualityTools` package in R, and I can't figure out why it uses one vector and rejects the next.

`pcr` happily takes something I produce with `rnorm`

```
x <- rnorm(100, mean = 7, sd = .5)
pcr(x, distribution = "normal", 6.5, 7.5)
```

But the vector I got from my data set throws an error

```
y <- na.omit(myData$vals)
pcr(y, distribution = "normal", 6.5, 7.5
```

> Error in `colMeans(x)` : `x` must be an array of at least two dimensions

I guess `colMeans` is in `pcr` somewhere, but when I call `colMeans` on `x` and `y`, I get that error for both.

But the values from my data set get rejected. They're numerics that came in as factors, I used `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` to format them. The only difference I can see is that in the environment, `x` is labeled as `num` while `y` is labeled as `atomic` but I can't figure out how that's different/why that difference effects the method.

edit:

`str(y)` looks like `atomic [1:2038] 7.13 7.12 7.09 7.1 7.1 7.1 7.09 7.07 7.1 7.09 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:4] 525 1548 2041 2042`

Apologies for poor formatting and etiquette, don't often ask questions.

Comment: How about you post `str(y)` and maybe we can make some sense of this.

Comment: What about `pcr(as.numeric(y), distribution = "normal", 6.5, 7.5)`?

Comment: That worked, thanks, but my question now is why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, if use `as.numeric(y)` it will work.

As to why this is happening, we'll need to look at the code for `pcr` which [is available on github](https://github.com/cran/qualityTools/blob/master/R/pcr_r.r).

`pcr` calls `colMeans` on the input - which needs a matrix or data frame (to be exact, "an array of two or more dimensions") as input. To get there, it checks input like this:

```
if (is.vector(x)) 
        x = as.data.frame(x)
```

Unfortunately, with the extra attributes added by `na.omit`, (you can see in the structure output: `- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'`), `is.vector()` is no longer true:

```
is.vector(na.omit(c(1, NA, 2)))
# [1] FALSE
```

If we look at `?vector` we can find this:

> `is.vector` returns `TRUE` if `x` is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes *other than names*. It returns `FALSE` otherwise.

So `is.vector` is at least behaving as documented. Thus you need to coerce your input back to a "true vector" with `as.numeric()` or `as.vector()` after the `na.omit()` line.

The `?na.omit` help also mentions adding the attributes:

> If `na.omit` removes cases, the row numbers of the cases form the `"na.action"` attribute of the result, of class `"omit"`.

With the `base` functions behaving as documented, this could perhaps be considered a bug in `pcr`. Rather than testing for `is.vector(x)`, perhaps it should be testing the dimensions directly, perhaps `if (length(dim(x) < 2) x = as.data.frame(x)`.